# Converting Bitmap to ImageSource

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm trying to take a screen shot and set it as background of a WPF window. 
This is my code to convert screenshot to ImageSource, I'm getting a NullReferenceException when converting from bitmap. How to do this properly?

```
    Dim screenSize = Forms.SystemInformation.PrimaryMonitorSize
    Dim bitmap = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height)
    Dim g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)
    g.CopyFromScreen(New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), screenSize)
    g.Flush()
    Dim c As ImageSourceConverter = New ImageSourceConverter()
    Dim img As ImageSource = c.ConvertFrom(bitmap)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap.aspx) method:

```
Dim hbitmap As IntPtr
Try    
    hbitmap = bitmap.GetHBitmap()
    Dim img As ImageSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(hbitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions())
    ...
Finally
    If hbitmap <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        DeleteObject(hbitmap)
    End If
End Try


...

<DllImport("gdi32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function DeleteObject(hObject As IntPtr)  As <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)> Boolean
End Function
```